# Android: Get correct coordinates with scaled and translated canvas

Tags: c#, android, coordinates

I am writing an Android (Xamarin) application which is able to zoom and pan an image. A user can also click on a position on the image. I need those coordinates on the image for later use.

The following code is zooming and panning the image:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    base.OnDraw(canvas);

    _maxX = canvas.Width;
    _maxY = canvas.Height;

    canvas.Translate(_posX, _posY);

    if (_scaleDetector.IsInProgress)
        canvas.Scale(_scaleFactor, _scaleFactor, _scaleDetector.FocusX, _scaleDetector.FocusY);
    else
        canvas.Scale(_scaleFactor, _scaleFactor, _lastGestureX, _lastGestureY);
}
```

So far so good, now I have some `MotionEvent` in use, which is a `LongPressListener`. I wrote the following code to translate the coordinates from the `MotionEvent` to the coordinates on the image:

```
var actualX = e.GetX() - (_parent._posX / _parent._scaleFactor);
var actualY = e.GetY() - (_parent._posY / _parent._scaleFactor);
```

`e` in this case is the frame of the image. The frame holds an image (which is `_parent`), the user can drag the image. `_parent._posX/Y` are changed when that happens. The user can also zoom the image, that's the `_scaleFactor`.

So, when a user taps anywhere in `e`, I need to translate those coordinates to the image coordinates.

Those two lines of code works, but when the user zooms in, the coordinates are off as you can see in the attached image:

[image: Screen recording]

The red dots represent the calculated positions. As you can see, if a user zooms in the coordinates gets more off. What's wrong in this calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it using a `Matrix`:

```
private float[] TranslateCoordinates(float[] coordinates)
{
    var matrix = new Matrix(Matrix);

    matrix.PreScale(_scaleFactor, _scaleFactor);
    matrix.PreTranslate(_posX, _posY);

    matrix.Invert(matrix);
    matrix.MapPoints(coordinates);

    return coordinates;
}
```

The `float[]` contains the values of `MotionEvent`'s `GetX()` and `GetY()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do this :-

```
  var actualX = (e.GetX() - _parent._posX) / _parent._scaleFactor;

  var actualY = (e.GetY() - _parent._posY) / _parent._scaleFactor;
```

Comment: Better, however the circles are placed like inversed over the axis now.

Comment: Instead of _parent._posX/Y, use actual translation of canvas. For this, first get matrix of canvas and then fetch transX/Y

Comment: As you can see I translate the canvas with those values: `canvas.Translate(_posX, _posY);`

Comment: Please post the code where _parent._posX/Y gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because the Canvas is not getting updated, try using `Canvas.UpdateLayout` after zooming.